# document type does not allow element "BR" here; assuming missing "LI" start-tag

Tags: html, list, validation, w3c, w3c-validation

How to do a list with is validated with HTML 4.01

I have something like this, but I get an error :( document type does not allow element "BR" here; assuming missing "LI" start-tag

```
<tr> 
<td colspan="2"> 
    <ol>
        <li><b>All</b>
        <br><br>
            <ol class="examplecalss">
                <li><a href="1.htm">exampletekst</a></li>
                <li><a href="2.htm">exampletekst</a></li>
                <li><a href="3.htm">exampletekst</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <br>
        <li>
        <b>exampletekst</b>
        <br><br>
            <ol class="examplecalss">
                <li><a href="4.htm">exampletekst</a></li>
                <li><a href="5.htm">exampletekst</a></li>
                <li><a href="6.htm">exampletekst</a><br>
                    <ul class="examplecalss">
                        <li><a href="7.htm">exampletekst</a></li>
                        <li><a href="8.htm">exampletekst</a></li>
                        <li><a href="9.htm">exampletekst</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="11.htm">exampletekst</a></li>
                <li><a href="12.htm">exampletekst</a></li>
                <li><a href="13.htm">exampletekst</a></li>
                </ol>
        </li>
        <br>

    </ol>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest `<br>` as a direct child to `ul` element, only `li` can be nested inside `ul` or `ol`, any other tag will be considered as invalid.

Instead, move those `br` inside `li` else if you've control over CSS, you can simply remove them and use `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` for `li` to get similar effect.

---

If you cannot modify your HTML, you can use jQuery to remove `br`

```
$('ol > br').remove();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NdTEb/1/)

Comment: hmm but how to make a space as <br>?

Comment: @JurekWerter Sorry but I didn't got you

Comment: @JurekWerter, you shouldn’t think in terms of `<br>` but in terms of empty space desired. Decide on its height in suitable units (preferably `em`) and set `margin` accordingly in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css to make that space, like this: ol>li {padding-top: 10px}. I didn't understaind your question well.be more speciffic.